# How can i create for example 5 folders out of an excel sheet with vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following vba code to create an folder structure with the data of the excel sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function MakePath& Lib "imagehlp.dll" Alias _
   "MakeSureDirectoryPathExists" (ByVal sPath$)

Sub CreatePaths()
Dim i&
With Tabelle1
For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
MakePath .Cells(i, "E").Text
Next
End With
End Sub
```

"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\test\H01\U01\UU01"

Each row is created as a folder structure in my chosen folder, until here it does what i need to. Column E adds column A-D and separates it with a backslash. Now i need to add for example 4 folders (A,B,C,D) in each folder of the column 'E' and i tried to add it but it does not work. What do i have to add to my vba code so the folders are created?

Feel free to ask questions.
[image: myExcelsheet]

Comment: Can you give a sample output that you want? Like you want something 4 separate folders in C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test so this certain directory will have a folder name H01, U01, UU01? Is this what you need?

Comment: Sure, for example the first row  C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\test\H01\U01\UU01
I want to add the folders "A","B","C","D" to the folder UU01, and i want to add it to each folder in the column "E" so every Folder "below" UU01

Comment: You can't create `"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\test\H01\U01\UU01"` unless `"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\test\H01\U01"` exists. You need to work through the path, level by level and where each level doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: No you missunderstood me, it creates every folder until the last one already, but i want to add 4 Folders into the last one.

Comment: @CLR The [MakeSureDirectoryPathExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680352(v=vs.85).aspx) can create the folder tree, it doesn't require the previous level folder.

Comment: Sorry, yes I see that now. Can't believe in all these years I've been using my own `make_directory()` sub!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one because you have a root folder in column A. We will call this is as our ParentDirectory and as we traverse on the inner folder which on Column B, C, D we will create individual folders name "A,B,C,D" respectively.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function MakePath& Lib "imagehlp.dll" Alias _
   "MakeSureDirectoryPathExists" (ByVal sPath$)

Sub CreatePaths()

Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
Dim currentDirectory As String, parentDirectory As String
With Tabelle1
For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    parentDirectory = .Cells(i, 1) & "\"
    For x = 2 To 4
        currentDirectory = parentDirectory & .Cells(i, x).Text & "\"
        MakePath currentDirectory
        MakePath currentDirectory & "A\"
        MakePath currentDirectory & "B\"
        MakePath currentDirectory & "C\"
        MakePath currentDirectory & "D\"
        parentDirectory = currentDirectory
    Next x
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That kinda works but, it has ABCD in every folder, unless the H01-H18. But i just need it in the UU01-UU24.

Comment: I've put the ABCD under "Next x" now it works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function MakePath& Lib "imagehlp.dll" Alias _
    "MakeSureDirectoryPathExists" (ByVal sPath$)

Sub CreatePaths()

Dim i&, subfolders As Variant, subfolder As Variant
subfolders = Split("A,B,C,D", ",")

With Tabelle1
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each subfolder In subfolders
            MakePath .Cells(i, "E").Text & "\" & subfolder
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gives me the Error that the variable for For Each has to be a Variant or Object

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me the same output as before.